# jQuery not all tables rows are getting selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the enterprise application where I need to remove all the classes of a specific table rows.

I am using following jQuery selector for selecting all the rows

```
var bodyTable =  $(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv table tbody");
var bodyRows = $(bodyTable).find("tr");
```

The HTML for the div in which table resides is in the following jsFiddle
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La7cQ/1/)

In jsFiddle it works as expected and returns all 11 rows but in the application it only selects the first row and the following code returns 1

```
$(bodyTable).find("tr").length;
```

I am not able to determine what could be stopping it.

Any pointers why jquery would only select first row?

Comment: Your code is crashing my browser

Comment: you mean jsFiddle code is crashing the browser?

Comment: you need to use like this `bodyTable.find("tr").length;` because `bodyTable=$(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv table tbody")`  http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/La7cQ/3/

Comment: Sounds like your code is conflicting with any other lines of code, you should try commenting out other code blocks to find out what's causing the issue.

Comment: @PranavRam I tried but the result is same it returns 1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/La7cQ/3/

Comment: Did you put your code inside the ready function of jquery?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute something on each row ... try this

```
$(bodyTable).find("tr").each(function(){
   //operation on each row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, It turned out be a case of putting the code in the wrong event.

Our application is event driven application and I was writing the code at initial event when the UI is being displayed.

@shhade slman comment made me look at the other events and after putting the same code in the data rendering event worked as expected. I knew it is something inside the application as the code in jsFiddle was working.

Thanks all for your input that nudged me into the right direction.